# ${\rm erf}$ question: I am stuck

Tags: calculus

can somebody help me? I am stuck at this problem.

> Show that
>   $\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{b}{\rm e}^{y}\,{\rm d}t
> =
> \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi\,}\,\left[{\rm erf}\left(b\right)
> -
> {\rm erf}\left(a\right)\right]}$ where $y = -t^{2}$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use integration by parts, then I guess you're supposed to use the definition of the error function

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^te^{-s^2}\,ds = \mathrm{erf}\,(t),$$

to get that

$$\int_a^b e^{-t^2}\,dt = \int_a^0 e^{-t^2}\,dt + \int_0^be^{-t^2}\,dt = \int_0^b e^{-t^2}\,dt - \int_0^ae^{-t^2}\,dt = \ldots$$

I leave it to you to finish this calculation.

Comment: But this will ask me to evaluate the indefinite integral: $\int e^-tsquared$? That is where I am confused.

Comment: But the error function is defined as that integral I provided you above; the objective now is to express those two integrals in terms of the error function without having to do any actual integration.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Thanks Christopher! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: make the substitution you are given ($y=-t^2$), and then integrate by parts.

Comment: We are not supposed to use integration by parts here. :(